# I am getting this error when I am using a PIPE in multiple module

Tags: javascript, angular, filter, pipe

> Error: Type ObjectIterationPipe is part of the declarations of 2
>   modules: AppModule and Tab1PageModule! Please consider moving
>   ObjectIterationPipe to a higher module that imports AppModule and
>   Tab1PageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and
>   includes ObjectIterationPipe then import that NgModule in AppModule
>   and Tab1PageModule.

If I am declaring in **appModule** then it is giving me different error.

Comment: check your declarations (of course) in both modules, you need to declare it only in higher, in AppModule for example.

Comment: It would be helpful for us if you could add the modules code

Comment: It would be great if you share your two modules code. let's assume you have Module A and Module B if you want to share anything other then services from A you can add those (component, pipes, directives) in exports of A, and when injecting A inside imports of B you can use that pipe within both A and B module.
Note :- Services(those added in providers) have global scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have the pipe declarated in `declaration` array in two modules.

Leave it only in AppModule. You have to remove `ObjectIterationPipe` from `declaration: [...]` in Tab1PageModule

The second option is to create another module for sharing instances between modules and name it for example `SharedModule` 
Then in `SharedModule` declare in `declarations` array the  `ObjectIterationPipe`.
Finally add `SharedModule` into `imports` of both `AppModule` and `Tab1PageModule`

Comment: If I am removing it from Tab1PageModule declaration it is giving me that The pipe 'objectIteration' could not be found.

Comment: okay so probably you should create another module like "shared module" and then declare only there your pipe. Then in both AppModule and Tab1PageModule import in imports array this module "SharedModule" - this way the architecture is the most clear

Comment: yeah, I have done it as well. I have created one core module declare all pipe in it and import it app module then the error is the same. 

This is a very weird error I am facing now. Anyway thanks for your immediate response.

Comment: So you cover all steps?
1. Create CoreModule and declare there Pipe
2. Remove Pipe declarations in both AppModule and Tab1PageModule
3. Import CoreModule in both AppModule and Tab1PageModule

Comment: I am writing this to thank you so much. I repeated this process once again and it resolved now.

Comment: Great! You can approve my answer then